# Is there a way to make a previously-public parameterless constructor private without making it a breaking change for protobuf (de)serialization?

Tags: c#, serialization, constructor, deserialization, protobuf-net

Given this class that is consumed by other projects and/or libraries:

```
[Serializable, DataContract]
public class MatchResult
{
    [DataMember(Order = 1)]
    public long MatchId {get; set;}

    [DataMember(Order = 2)]
    public long TeamId {get; set;}
    
    [DataMember(Order = 3)]
    public MatchStatus Status {get; set;}

    [DataMember(Order = 4)]
    public List<AgentMatchInfo> AgentMatchInformation {get; set;}

    public MatchResult()
    {
       // I want to make this a private one, without the consumers seeing 
       // errors that their declaration using 
       // this current public constructor is no loner applicable.
    }
}
```

How do you properly make the currently-`public` parameterless constructor `private` for the purpose of protobuf (de)serialization without making it a breaking change when the constructor declaration is currently being called explicitly by consumers?

Is making the current `public` constructor have an optional parameter while adding a `private` parameterless constuctor a good practice and will play nice with protobuf?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Protobuf-net *should* be fine with a non-public constructor. Are you using a restricted framework, perhaps? On most, I'd be genuinely surprised if simply using a private constructor (`private MatchResult() {}`) didn't work.

An alternative is to skip the constructor *entirely*, which you can do by using `[ProtoContract(SkipConstructor = true)]` instead of `[DataContract]`, and `[ProtoMember(N)]` instead of `[DataMember(Order = N)]` - however, I wonder if this will fail on those frameworks where a non-public constructor failed.

Comment: Accepting this answer because apparently, there was some misunderstanding between me and a colleague regarding protobuf serialization and public constructors. For now I'm leaving the constructor public.